# Any other solutions other than Pause and Resume flow interview?

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, flow-interviews

My requirement : I have a simple flow where in the flow sends an email to the contact but now client wants to first receive the email to their specific sales rep and if everything is ok, then would want to continue and click on 'next' which actually sends out the email to the contact. If the email for some reason does not comply that is if one of the merge fields is missing data or does have wrong data which Sales rep would find after receiving it in their inbox.

He/She would want to pause and go back to the record and correct the wrong data i.e update the particular record (In my case this record is from Account and the screen flow would be a quick action that merges fields from contact/Account into the email template that is sent out) and resume the flow to send the email once again.

I have been thinking to pause the flow that is when the user clicks on the 'Pause' button screen he/she enters the reason and thus exiting from the flow. I would want to pull up my apex action again after this screen that would send the email with updated data. This approach would work but I guess I need to educate the sales rep on how to use the pause flow interview.

My goal is to provide the option to the user such that they can pause the flow, update the record and then come back to flow to resume it and send out the email again with the corrected data.

I was wondering if there could be any other solution other than pause and resume.

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is an example of a [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If your goal is having the "correct" content in the email, please edit your question and describe this goal.

Comment: Thanks, I just did  update my question with more details and also my end goal along with it.

Comment: flow orchestrator?

Comment: I cannot use flow orchestrator because my flow is a screen flow and is not a record triggered flow.

Answer (score 0):

I think I might try a different approach.  If the reason that your user wants to send a test email is to verify that all fields are filled out on the record, instead of sending an email to check that, I'd use a decision element to check that your fields are filled out prior to sending the email to the contact.  Or you could make those fields required on the record.

Your test email is going to count against your email limits for the day, so unless there is another reason, I'd just check that the fields contained values before sending the email.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but what if the rep would want to update the particular record (In my case this record is from Account and the screen flow would be a quick action that merges fields from contact/Account into the email template that is sent out)as they would want to update those fields on the record ?

Comment: When your flow checks that your fields are all filled out, you could display another screen that has either some text inputs for them to input missing information, or instructs them to go back to the record and fill out whatever info is necessary on the related records.